# Annotated django queryset is getting ignored during serialization

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a `ModelViewSet` where I want to annotate the `list()` response. I've extended the queryset with an annotation and added the field to the serializer, but the serializer just ignores the new data and doesn't add the field at all in the final data.

I am using a customized `get_queryset()` too (show abbreviated here) which is definitely getting called and producing the right annotations. It just doesn't show up in the REST API response.
If I set `default=None` on the serializer field definition, it appears in the response.

```
class SequenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unread=serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    .....

class SequenceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,ScopedProtectedResourceView):
    authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication]
    queryset = Sequence.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SequenceSerializer
    .....

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Sequence.objects.all().filter(<..... some filter>)           
        queryset = queryset.annotate(unread=FilteredRelation('unreadseq',
            condition=Q(unreadseq__userid=self.request.user)))
        print("Seq with unread",queryset.values('id','unread')) ## <<<<this shows the correct data
        return queryset

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data) ##<<< this is missing the annotation
```

I have been banging my head against this all day and I can't for the life of me see what's going wrong.
Any ideas please?

--
more info:

```
class UnreadSeq(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seqid = models.ForeignKey(Sequence, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together=('seqid','userid')
        verbose_name = "UnreadSeq"
        verbose_name_plural = "UnreadSeqs"

class Sequence(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False,blank=False)
    .....
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Sequence"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sequences"
```

Comment: check `ScopedProtectedResourceView` mixin for get_queryset/list override

Comment: I've had a look here: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views/details.html#mixins and I don't see any override.

Comment: Can you show the serializer ?

Comment: The SequenceSerializer has nothing else relevant in it - beyond what I've already show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this annotation don't return **Integer**. Try to annotate (you want to **COUNT** unreadseq) like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    mytopics=getMyTopics(self.request,False)
    queryset = Sequence.objects.all().filter(<..... some filter>)

    count_unreadseq = Count('unreadseq', filter=Q(unreadseq__userid=self.request.user))
    queryset=queryset.annotate(unread=count_unreadseq)

    ...
```

**EDITED** after comments to get unreadseq ids

```
def get_queryset(self):
    mytopics=getMyTopics(self.request,False)
    queryset = Sequence.objects.all().filter(<..... some filter>)

    unreadseq_ids = UnreadSeq.objects.filter(seqid=OuterRef('pk'), userid=self.request.user).values('pk')

    queryset=queryset.annotate(unread=Subquery(unreadseq_ids))
    ...
```

Also you need to edit serializer:

```
class SequenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unread=serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    .....
```

Comment: Ah, I see. However, I don't want the count, I want the id of the related object. 'unreadseq__id'. I will see if that helps. Thanks

Comment: I've added the relevant model sections to the OP. I've tried to get the id out of the annotate myself - but I can't work it out. I can change the serializer to reference the actual UnreadSeq model if that helps, but the id would be fine if you can show me how to get it. Thanks again

Comment: This works perfectly. Thankyou very much! - but I didn't need the serializer change as it was guaranteed to have only one match.